# Wrapping NSAttributedString around another NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, word-wrap

I want to know if it is possible to have an NSAttributedString (call it NS1) floating top left within a container NSAttributedString (call it NS2), so that the attributed text within NS2 wraps around the text in NS1. Ive looked at a number of examples where they have text wrapping around other objects, but they aren't using attributed strings. The output would then look something like:

**NS1 Line 1** NS2 bla bla bla bla
**NS1 Line 2** bla word wrapped bla
bla bla still wrapping bla bla etc

Maybe the question should really be can I have a paragraph inside an NSAttributedString that has text flowing around it?

Comment: I'd recommend using core text and exclusion paths as you would wrapping text around an image, but then insert the attributed string.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan, I'll read up on how to do that.